# How to export bloopsaphone tunes to MP3?

Tags: ruby, mp3, portaudio

I have found a few places that have exported their [Bloopsaphone](https://github.com/mental/bloopsaphone) tunes to MP3 but I cannot find out how to do this.

[Here's an example](http://freqvibez.net/music/cheeky_drat.mp3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Bloopsaphone version 0.4.1 by Viking: `gem install viking-bloopsaphone`.

That version's Bloops object got a brand-new #record() method to save the output to a .wav file. You can turn it then into mp3 using your favourite encoder.